# Can I use backup gem with whenever in docker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, backup, whenever

Environment:

- Docker version 20.10.10,
- Docker image: from Ruby 2.7.2
  Gems:
- Backup: 5.0.0.beta.3
- Rails: 6.1.5
- whenever: 1.0.0

In schedule.rb, I have updated the command

```
every 1.minute do
  command "/usr/local/bundle/bin/backup perform -t db_backup -c /app/Backup/config.rb"
end
```

If I run the above command manually on docker bash mode, It works fine. However, when it runs from cron, there is an error showing the following:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:277:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem backup (>= 0.a) with executable backup (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems.rb:296:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /usr/local/bundle/bin/backup:23:in `<main>'
```

May I know what is a proper way for using backup gem with docker?